# Transform radial gradient in kinetic.js

Tags: transformation, kineticjs, radial-gradients

I want to apply a transform to a radial gradient using Kinetic.js.

I have, for example a 200x200 rectangle with a radial gradient from the center (white) to the sides. How can I scale only the gradient, so that it becomes ellipse-shaped instead of circle-shaped, but keeping the square form (and 200x200 size) of the rectangle intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here’s how to create an oval radial gradient fill in KineticJS**

KineticJS nodes (like your rectangle) can use images a fill using “fillPatternImage”.

So you can fill your rectangle with an image of an oval radiant gradient.

You can automatically generate your gradient image using the “ovalGradientURL()” function below.

Of course, you can modify this function to do any variety of gradient shapes/colors that you need.  The return value of this function is a dataURL that you can use as the source of an Image().  Simple as this: myImage.src=ovalGradientURL();

ovalGradientURL() works by:

- Creating a hidden canvas
- Filling the canvas with a radial gradient
- Making the gradient oval by scaling the radial gradient: scale(2,1);

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jsKaB/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
      canvas{ border:1px solid red; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>

      // draw KineticJS stuff
      function draw(gradientImage) {

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 50,
          y: 25,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          fillPatternImage: gradientImage,
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 4
        });

        layer.add(rect);
        stage.add(layer);
      }


      // Create an image of an oval radial gradient
      // Use this image as fill for the kineticjs rect

      function ovalGradientURL(){
            // new up a canvas
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width=200;
            canvas.height=200;
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var cx=canvas.width/4;
            var cy=canvas.height/2;
            // draw a rectangle filled with an oval gradient
            context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var grad = context.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, 15, cx, cy, 130);
            grad.addColorStop(0, 'white');
            grad.addColorStop(.8, 'blue');
            context.scale(2,1);
            context.fillStyle = grad;
            context.fill();
            return(canvas.toDataURL());
      }

      // create an Image() out of the canvas.toDataURL()
      // then start KineticJS draw()
      var img=new Image();
      img.onload=function(){
          draw(img);
      }
      img.src=ovalGradientURL();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice workaround, but actually transforming the gradient itself is not possible in Kinetic.js, or is it?

Comment: No, not possible to "ScaleX" a gradient fill.  You can get tantalizingly close---You *can* scale an image that's being used as a pattern fill, but not a gradient fill.